# Trying to Map Yelp API repsonse

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, fetch-api, array.prototype.map

I am using the Yelp API (by making requests to it using https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ as a proxy—because the Yelp API itself isn’t CORS-enabled) to attempt to create an app very similar to a Yelp search for my own practice. I am able to get the response into my browser's console. The response has an array named businesses with the businesses that match the search. I am trying to use `.(map)` to map through the businesses array. However, I keep getting `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`.

The reponse I receive from the Yelp API is below. Thanks
[Yelp API Response Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVdLx.png)

Also if there is any other tips about javascript that come to mind when looking at my code please share as I am very early into my programming career.

```
const Yelp = {
  getAccessToken: function() {
    if(accessToken) {
      return new Promise(resolve => resolve(accessToken));
    };
    return fetch(accessTokenUrl, {
      method: 'POST'
    }).then(response => response.json()).then(jsonResponse => {
     accessToken = jsonResponse.access_token;
    })
  },

  search: function(term,location,sortBy) {
    return this.getAccessToken().then(() => {
      const yelpRetrieveUrl = `${corsAnywhereUrl}https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search?term=${term}&location=${location}&sort_by=${sortBy}`;
      return fetch(yelpRetrieveUrl, {
        headers: {Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`}
    });
  }).then(jsonResponse => {
  if(1 > 0){
    console.log('true!!!!');
    return jsonResponse.businesses.map(business => {
      return {
        id: business.id,
        imageSrc: business.image_url,
        name: business.name,
        address: business.location.address1,
        city: business.location.city,
        state: business.location.state,
        zipCode: business.location.zip_code,
        category: business.categories,
        rating: business.rating,
        reviewCount: business.review_count
      };
    });
  } else {
    console.log('FALSE')
  }

  })
}

};
```

Comment: Consider accepting the answer as resolved?

Comment: Thank you for mentioning this, I didn't realize that I needed to accept an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fetch(myRequest).then(function(response) {
    var contentType = response.headers.get("content-type");
    if(contentType && contentType.includes("application/json")) {
      return response.json();
    }
    throw new TypeError("Oops, we haven't got JSON!");
  })
  .then(function(json) { /* process your JSON further */ })
  .catch(function(error) { console.log(error); });
```

You might search for the **[jsonResponse#json](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)** function to turn your json dataset into a real object that you can process in JavaScript.

*And because you asked for it:* As you are using Promises, make use of the **[Promise#Catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch)** function to handle upcoming errors. Don't let the browser handle them, because they can have different behaviors in different browsers.

And probably remove the *1 > 0* check, because it will always be true, but I think this was only for test purposes.

I hope I could help you! I might append the code later since I'm currently on mobile.